# Windows server 2008 r2 unlimiting the allowed number of logon to a single user

Tags: windows-server-2008

i got a server running windows server 2008, and i got a user which everyone can connect to via Remote desktop!

when 2 users a are logged to the server, it's fine.
but when 3 users are logged on, it says one of the other 2 should logoff!

my question is, how i disable the limitation of concurrent logons to a single users?

Comment: This question is not about programming and belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 7):

The terminal server basic install is "Remote Administration" mode which allows 2 users for, er, admin stuff.

If you want it as full solution (run apps, use > 2 users etc) then it's "application mode" and it costs money

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the Remote Desktop Session Host role in Server Manager and buy some CALs.

Answer (score -1):

You can allow multiple logins for a single user which would solve it for a shared admin account.

```
 1. Start regedit
 2. Check out the follwoing registry key
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer

 3. If the fSingleSessionPerUser value doesn’t exist, create a new DWORD value named     fSingleSessionPerUser

 4. Open the fSingleSessionPerUser value. The possible values for this setting are as follows:
      0×0 Allow multiple sessions per user
      0×1 Force each user to a single session

 5. Save
```

Comment: It'd be a breach of licensing to use it in this way, though

Comment: I think @Dan would be correct in his comment!

Comment: No, it'll allow one user to log in with 2 different sessions but then you won't be able to have a third person log in.  This answers the question of the title, but not the actual question. Not a violation of licenses, though.